# Expected move on std::vector's elements but copy encountered instead when trying to pass it as a parameter

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Why is the following code calling `a`'s copy constructors?

```
class a {
public:
    a(int x) : x_(x) { std::cout << "a constructor" << std::endl; }
    a(a&& a_) { std::cout << "a move constructor" << std::endl; }
    a(const a& a_) { std::cout << "a copy constructor" << std::endl; }

private:
    int x_;
};

class b {
public:
    b(std::vector<a>&& v) : v_(std::move(v)) {}

private:
    std::vector<a> v_;
};

int main() {
    b s({2, 3, 4, 5, 6});
}
```

The output is the following:

```
a constructor
a constructor
a constructor
a constructor
a constructor
a copy constructor
a copy constructor
a copy constructor
a copy constructor
a copy constructor
```

I was expecting no copy since the vector is created in place and passed as a rvalue reference and after that moved. What's actually happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::initializer_list<T>` is a wrapper around an array of `const T` objects. (More precisely, [`std::initializer_list<T>::reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is `const T&`). Notice the `const`. It has to be like that, because its elements can be literals.

This means that the constructor of `std::vector` taking `std::initializer_list` has to *copy* the elements from the list into the vector, it cannot move them.

Comment: More precisely the reason is that the constructor takes a `std::initializer_list<T>` (where `T` is the value type of the vector) and is not templated to take an `std::initializer_list<X>` (with some `X`). Otherwise the `a` s could be constructed by the vector.